# MATLAB regexp reject match if condition occurs

Tags: regex, matlab

I'm trying to use MATLAB's regexp to try and filter out a large ASCII datafile. Typically the file contains comma-separated entries that have about 15 fields:

```
$PINS2,234572.485,2017,1493375479,65616,0.6356,-0.0113,-0.0411,-0.7709,-0.119,-0.071,0.030,34.19859875,-118.16703693,297.113*2b
```

But sometimes I have lines that look like:

```
$PINS2,234572.677,2017,14933,-0.255,-0.534,-9.671*25
```

which I want to reject. I came up with a simple check - if there are 14 commas in the matched text, keep it. If there are less, reject it. Can I use dynamic regexp to perform this action? If so, how? I tried to use

```
(?(?@count($1,",")==14)(?<=PINS2)[-,.\s0-9]*(?=*))
```

as an expression, but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the check have to be a regex?

Comment: It seems like the most efficient thing to do for a large file. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
^(?=(?:[^,]+,){14}).*$
```

- `^` Beginning of string.
- `(?=` Positive lookahead.
- `(?:[^,]+,){14}` Non capturing group. Matches anything which is not a comma, followed by a comma. The non capturing group is matched 14 times.
- `)` Closes lookahead.
- `.*` Match anything greedily.
- `$` Assert position end of string.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/DdpBjV/1).

---

**MATLAB** demo:

First string:

```
>> str = '$PINS2,234572.485,2017,1493375479,65616,0.6356,-0.0113,-0.0411,-0.7709,-0.119,-0.071,0.030,34.19859875,-118.16703693,297.113*2b'
>> regexp(str,'^(?=(?:[^,]+,){14}).*$','match')
ans =

1×1 cell array

{'$PINS2,234572.485,2017,1493375479,65616,0.6356,-0.0113,-0.0411,-0.7709,-0.119,-0.071,0.030,34.19859875,-118.16703693,297.113*2b'}
```

Second string:

```
>> str = '$PINS2,234572.677,2017,14933,-0.255,-0.534,-9.671*25'
>> regexp(str,'^(?=(?:[^,]+,){14}).*$','match')

ans =

  0×0 empty cell array
```

---

Alternatively, you may simply check how many commas there are in the string and filter accordingly:

```
>> str = '$PINS2,234572.485,2017,1493375479,65616,0.6356,-0.0113,-0.0411,-0.7709,-0.119,-0.071,0.030,34.19859875,-118.16703693,297.113*2b'
>> nnz(str == ',')

ans =

    14
```

Comment: Thank you! I used a slightly edited version of your suggestion because for some reason MATLAB doesn't pick up on the carriage return in my file. I used :

'(?<=PINS2,)(?=(?:[^,]+,){13}).*(?=*)'

To pick up the part only between PINS2 and the * (avoids the carriage return problem).

Comment: You are welcome. Ah yes, you must be reading the file with `fileread` right?

Comment: Yes I am. Actually, allow me to correct myself. The line I wrote above seemed to show correct behavior for individual lines, but when I apply it to the entire text, it just gives me everything from right after first PINS2 to the very last *. I guess I may have to look for something better than fileread, which will actually see end of line characters

Comment: @SiddharthKrishnamoorthy can you put the full text resulting from the fileread [here](https://regex101.com/) ? Then click Save Regex in the top left corner and send me the link.

Comment: Well so the thing is, when I copy paste the text of the data into that regex link, what you originally posted works pretty well, because the text editor understands the line feed and carriage return characters. The regex is [here](https://regex101.com/r/GibyHT/1). Fileread is doing something that's somehow not making it read the line feed character and I get everything in one long character array.

Comment: Or try [this](https://regex101.com/r/GibyHT/3), or [this](https://regex101.com/r/GibyHT/4), the `(?s)` flag is enabled by default in [regexp](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)

Comment: In the above two links, if you notice, it also picks up the shortened PINS2 line a few rows down in the match. I tried the pastebin link but the problem's the same, when I copy paste from the original file, the new line will appear. In my code when I run it, it just gives me one cell with everything from the beginning to the end.

Comment: You need `(?<=\$PINS2,)(?=(?:[^,\n]+,){13}).*$` then, since you are matching the first `,` in the lookbehind. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/GibyHT/5).

Comment: Ah I think that extra \n did the trick. Just for my understanding, what happens when you don't have that \n? Because it needs to get exactly 13 instances of that pattern right?

As a side note, I edited that top line a little bit and finally found one that works for my actual file - '(?<=PINS2,)(?=(?:[^,\n]+,){13})[^\n]*(?=\*)' 
This one too, I'm not sure I fully understand why adding that clause to look for characters that are not \n ends up splitting lines, when the * at the end of each line should already do it.

Thank you for all your great help!

Comment: If you are working with a multiline file, a negated character set such as `[^,]` will match new lines too, therefore the match will continue on the next line and find the comma separated entries there. For this reason, you see a match on an unwanted line. Does this help?

Comment: I see, thank you for your help. I'm still learning the intricacies of regular expressions. The learning curve is a little steep but it seems like a very powerful tool.

Comment: You are welcome. Indeed, they can be very powerful. Useful tool across multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were able to come up with a regexp solution, but I would suggest skipping regexp.

```
function profFunc()

    n = 10;

    str = repmat("$PINS2,234572.485,2017,1493375479,65616,0.6356,-0.0113,-0.0411,-0.7709,-0.119,-0.071,0.030,34.19859875,-118.16703693,297.113*2b",100000,1);
    str(50) = "$PINS2,234572.677,2017,14933,-0.255,-0.534,-9.671*25";

    str = join(str,newline);

    tic
    for i = 1:n
        result_1 = regexp(str,'(?<=PINS2,)(?=(?:[^,\n]+,){13})[^\n]*(?=*)','match');
    end
    toc

    tic
    for i = 1:n
        result_2 = splitlines(str);
        result_2(count(result_2,',') ~= 14) = [];
    end
    toc
end

>> profFunc
Elapsed time is 7.321635 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.716751 seconds.
```

The regexp used drops the '$PINS2,' and the '*2b' which you could achieve with extractBefore and extractAfter if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! Do you think maybe the time difference is because you're running regexp line by line in a for loop? In my case I have the entire text in one block, including the newline and carriage return, so it seems to run much faster. I will try splitlines out and see what it does too. Thanks.

Comment: The loops are just for timing so all the work is done N times.